# How to use CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER in guzzle

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6, guzzle

I'm using a extension of my PHP website for SSO which uses guzzle. It gives this error when running it.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 35: error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in.....
```

When I went to the website mentioned in the error for error 35 it says:

```
CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)

A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read 
the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths,
permissions), passwords, and others.
```

Top of the website tells this.

```
No matter what, using the curl_easy_setopt option CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER is a good idea as it will 
give you a human readable error string that may offer more details about the cause of the error 
than just the error code.
```

As mentioned in the website how do I use [CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER.html) in guzzle.

Any answers are appreciated.

Please let me know what I should do.

Comment: It seems that [curl_setopt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) does not support `CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER`. Can't find it in Php manual.

Comment: @UmairKhan See [this](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2749#issuecomment-683451932) In this comment he says that it's possible with guzzle but he didn't mention how.

Comment: In PHP, the error buffer is instead provided using [curl_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: @DanielStenberg then how can it be made in guzzle